# Dotnet JWT Bearer TokenValidationParameters issue - Unauthorized? Role(Policy) based authorization doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, token

I changed the setting in the TokenValidationParameters (ValidateIssuer,ValidateAudience) from False to True.

**What the settings used to be (startup)** - everything was working perfectly.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                };
            });
```

Now every call to the API the requires to authorized stopped working.

**The new settings** - stopped working

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                };
            });
```

Every call to the API that needs to be authorized now is getting unauthorized.

**This is my token service:**

```
    public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration config, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));
    }
    public async Task<string> CreateToken(AppUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Does anyone can please explain to me what causes it so I could learn. And how can I fix it ? I tried many ways but unfortunately, nothing seems to work for me.
Thank you so much.

**This is the code at GitHub just in case :** https://github.com/davidax0204/HeroMain.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience` to `true`, you should set value for `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience` when creating `JWT` and `SecurityTokenDescriptor`

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = creds,
            Audience = "YourAudience",
            Issuer = "YourIssuer"
        };
```

And adding same value to `TokenValidationParameters` properties

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "YourIssuer",

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "YourAudience"
                };
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! could you maybe explain a little further why that issue happened?